# rails_admin throws undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

Here's my model.  Working without errors on other similar models.
Not sure even how to troubleshoot this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
class OrderProduct
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Token

validates :quantity, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }

before_save :pre_save
after_save :post_save

token :field_name => :code, :pattern => "%C3%d7%C2"

field :quantity, type: Integer, :default => 1
field :notes, type: String
field :fit_satisfactory, type: Boolean, :default => true, overwrite: true
field :alteration_cost, type: Float, default: 0.0
field :fit_status_saved, type: Date, default: nil
field :initials, type: String
field :last_product_type_order, type: String, default: nil
auto_increment :sequence, :seed => 10000

belongs_to :order_product_status

belongs_to :product, autosave: true
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :product_fit
has_many :product_fit_entry_values, autosave: true

embeds_many :customizations, class_name: "OrderProductCustomization"
```

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting: [see image url] (http://i.imgur.com/WPj7hky.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like others have encountered that same problem and posted it on the rails_admin github page:

- [Issue 1852](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1852)

Some people have replied with work arounds, feel free to try those. However, the issue is still open so rails_admin hasn't been officially patched yet.